# Automatically generate copy of file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a .xlsm file of which I need a new copy every day. It is a tasklist with checkboxes. I have built in a button which I can click so it automatically saves a copy of the file with the current date in the title. Now I am looking for a way to get this file saved automatically every day, without me having to press the button. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: think about what you do with the .xlsm file every day ... use that action as a trigger to do the save

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Workbook_Open` event to

- Check the current value of `ThisWorkbook.Name` to see if it includes todays date.
- If not, execute `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` with the new file name that includes todays date.

Net result, the first time the book is opened each day, it will be saved as a new file.  Subsequent openings that day will do nothing.